# Curved lines in Graph view flutter

Tags: flutter, graph, family-tree, hourglass, flutter-custompaint

How do I achieve curved lines for connecting nodes in graphite or graph view? Like mind map curves I mentioned the image below but I want to implement the curved arrows in graphite.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to implement a family tree? can you tell more aboute what you exactly want to implement?